# Teradata and JDBC driver - classnotfoundexception ...but its there?

Tags: java, linux, classpath, teradata

Trying to work with a JDBC connection to Teradata.  I've loaded the tdgssconfig.jar and terajdbc4.jar file and adding them to the classpath with javac when I compile in Linux.  But I still get a ClassnotFoundException when trying to compile.

I've not worked with java in a while, but I've scoured the net and it looks like it should work.

Simple Code:

```
import java.sql.*;
class TDtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(classpath);

        Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
    }
}
```

*.jars are definitely there:

```
[user1@box java]# ls -l /home/user1/test/java/libs/*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 2405 Oct 26 12:00 /home/user1/test/java/libs/tdgssconfig.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 873860 Oct 26 12:00 /home/user1/test/java/libs/terajdbc4.jar
```

verbose error log - it looks like the classpath is right to me:

```
javac -verbose -cp ".:/home/user1/test/java/libs/tdgssconfig.jar:/home/user1/test/java/libs/terajdbc4.jar" TDtest.java
[parsing started TDtest.java]
[parsing completed 21ms]
[search path for source files: .,/home/user1/test/java/libs/tdgssconfig.jar,/home/user1/test/java/libs/terajdbc4.jar]
[search path for class files: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/jce.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/charsets.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/classes,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar,.,/home/user1/test/java/libs/tdgssconfig.jar,/home/user1/test/java/libs/terajdbc4.jar]
[loading java/lang/Object.class(java/lang:Object.class)]
[loading java/lang/String.class(java/lang:String.class)]
[checking TDtest]
[loading java/lang/Class.class(java/lang:Class.class)]
[loading java/lang/Error.class(java/lang:Error.class)]
[loading java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.class(java/lang:ClassNotFoundException.class)]
[loading java/lang/Exception.class(java/lang:Exception.class)]
[loading java/lang/Throwable.class(java/lang:Throwable.class)]
[loading java/lang/RuntimeException.class(java/lang:RuntimeException.class)]
TDtest.java:4: unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
```

I've tried un-jar'ing the jdbc jar's and they definitely have com/teradata/jdbc/TeraDriver.class in them.

I'm at a loss.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is not looking for the class `com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver` from your jar file, it is reacting to the `Class.forName()` statement.

As `Class.forName()` throws `ClassNotFoundException` which is a [checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation), you will need to handle it.

You could either surround the exception in a `try/catch' block or throw the exception to compile:

```
 class TDtest  {
   public static void main(String[] args) {    
      System.out.println(classpath);

      try {
         Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         // more error handling..
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isnt about your classpath. Just that you would want to wrap your Class.forName line with a try/catch block and catch the checked exception ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 try {
    Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver").newInstance();

     } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.ncr.teradata.TeraDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at com.ebay.quality.bp.Z_Query_Teradata.main(Z_Query_Teradata.java:15)
```

When I checked my pom.xml file under Dependency Hierarchy tab, I found out that I had test next to the dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.thirdparty.teradata</groupId>
  <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
  <version>14.10.00.17</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I removed the line with test scope and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a ClassNotFoundException with version 16.20.00.06.
I switched to 15.10.00.37 
It works now.
My guess is the 16.20.00.06 works with a newer version of Java than I have.